# If motherboard is completely broken, can we just `sysprep` on new machine? If plausible, how?

Tags: windows, windows-10, clone, sysprep, chipset

When we move, `sysprep` is what we turn for. However, if we can't do that beforehand, what to do to make the old installation work on new machine?

Comment: Sometimes you can just image old hdd into new system hdd and it just works if there are not too much changes. Give that a try first?

Comment: As discussed in this [question](https://superuser.com/q/1269897/213131) the most likely issue that will keep you from moving a Windows image to another motherboard is the storage drivers.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Til today I still wonder what keeps microsoft from having this kind of **emergency** feature?

Comment: @Darius Unfortunately, broken motherboards mostly have aged enough already, so you would want to upgrade it anyway, wouldn't you?